# Android Programming passing an element of an Arraylist to a fragment tab display

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist

I have an API set up that retrieves all of the information that I am collection on a certain food dish. As the dishes are returned they are stored in an arraylist and are then supposed to be displayed. The first fragment works as planned and displays everything properly but I need to pass the other dish data to the second and third fragments. Any advice on how to accomplish this?   Dish 1 -> fragment1 ... Dish 2 -> fragment2 ... Dish 3 -> fragment3

Below is the class where all of the fragments are handled and created.

public class ItemDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final String TAG = "ItemDetailActivity";
private ArrayList<MenuItemDetail> menuItemDetails;
private ArrayList<String> foundTextItems = new ArrayList<>();

//the following is for the fragments
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_detail);

    menuItemDetails = new ArrayList<>();

    foundTextItems = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(OcrCaptureActivity.FOUND_TEXT);

    for (String foundText: foundTextItems) {
        fetchDishInformation(foundText);
    }
    //the following is for the fragments
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Starting");

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    setupViewPager(mViewPager);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

}
//this is for fragments
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
    SectionsPagerAdapter adapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new tab1(), "Tab 1");
    adapter.addFragment(new tab2(), "Tab 2");
    adapter.addFragment(new tab3(), "Tab 3");


    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
// above section is for fragments

private void fetchDishInformation(String text) {
    text = text.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]","");
    text = text.replaceAll(" ","%20");
    String url = "https://seefood-server.herokuapp.com/nutrition/" + text;

    final JsonObjectRequest getMenuItems = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            //Log.d(TAG, "Api Response is! " + response);

            try {
                JSONObject menuItem = response.getJSONArray("foods").getJSONObject(0);

                String id = checkStringForNull("tag_id", menuItem.getJSONObject("tags"));

                String name = checkStringForNull("food_name", menuItem);
                String image = checkStringForNull("highres", menuItem.getJSONObject("photo"));
                String serving_size =  menuItem.getInt("serving_qty") + checkStringForNull("serving_unit", menuItem);

                Double calories = checkDoubleForNull("nf_calories", menuItem);
                Double totalFat = checkDoubleForNull("nf_total_fat", menuItem);
                Double saturatedFat = checkDoubleForNull("nf_saturated_fat", menuItem);
                Double cholesterol = checkDoubleForNull("nf_cholesterol", menuItem);
                Double sodium = checkDoubleForNull("nf_sodium", menuItem);
                Double total_carbs = checkDoubleForNull("nf_total_carbohydrate", menuItem);
                Double fiber= checkDoubleForNull("nf_dietary_fiber", menuItem);
                Double sugars = checkDoubleForNull("nf_sugars", menuItem);
                Double protein = checkDoubleForNull("nf_protein", menuItem);
                Double potassium = checkDoubleForNull("nf_potassium", menuItem);

                MenuItemDetail newMenuItem = new MenuItemDetail(id, name, image, serving_size, calories, totalFat, saturatedFat, cholesterol, sodium, total_carbs, fiber, sugars, protein, potassium);
                menuItemDetails.add(newMenuItem);

                setDetailScreen(newMenuItem);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.v("JSON", "EXC" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                setDetailScreenFail();
            }
        }

        private void setDetailScreenFail() {
            TextView itemName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            itemName.setText("We couldn't find that item!");
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Api Error is! " + error);
        }
    });

    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(getMenuItems);

}

private String checkStringForNull(String itemName, JSONObject menuItem) {
    String itemValue = "n/a";
    try {
        itemValue = menuItem.isNull(itemName) ? itemValue: menuItem.getString(itemName);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return itemValue;
}

private double checkDoubleForNull(String itemName, JSONObject menuItem) {
    Double itemValue = 0.0;
    try {
        itemValue = menuItem.isNull(itemName) ? itemValue : menuItem.getDouble(itemName);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return itemValue;
}

private void setDetailScreen(MenuItemDetail menuItem) {
    // System.out.println(menuItem);

    TextView itemName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_name);
    itemName.setText(menuItem.getName());

    TextView serving_size = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.serving_size);
    serving_size.setText("Serving size: " + menuItem.getServingSize());

    TextView totalFat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total_fat);
    totalFat.setText((Double.toString(menuItem.getTotalFat()) + " Total Fat"));

    TextView calories = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.calories);
    calories.setText((Double.toString(menuItem.getCalories()) + " Calories"));

    TextView carbs = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.carbs);
    carbs.setText((Double.toString(menuItem.getTotal_carbs()) + " Carbs"));

    TextView protein = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.protein);
    protein.setText((Double.toString(menuItem.getProtein()) + " Protein"));


    // Log.d(TAG, "Menu Image is! " + menuItem.getImage());
    ImageView itemPic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.dish_image);
    Picasso.with(itemPic.getContext())
            .load(menuItem.getImage())
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(itemPic);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ItemDetailActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(OcrCaptureActivity.FOUND_TEXT, foundTextItems);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

}
```

}

Comment: Number of fragments is static ?

Comment: No, the user can select anywhere from 1 to 3 items which would lead to 1 to 3 fragments of results to be generated.